# How to add something after a line grep found?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, newline

I would like to see whenever the ping to a specific server goes down.

So at the moment I have something like this: `ping 8.8.8.8 | grep time=11 && date`

This pings google and prints every line that has a ping of 11.x that is just for testing so that I have some output that is not there all the time but often enough that I can test this. And then I have && date that I thought would print the date when grep finds the string.. But it does not. So my question now Is how can I get it so that in every line that grep spits out I can append the current timestamp. Or what would be even better is to have it as a prefix in front of every line that grep spits out. Is this possible with one command? Or do I need a simple shell script?

Thanks in advance. I hope I get an answer soon. :)

Also merry x-mas to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if it works for you:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 |  while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done | grep time=13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn the setup around to check when a remote host becomes available by using `while ! ping ...` Example, in case your path to `8.8.8.8` goes down:

```
declare -i cnt=0; while ! ping -c 1 8.8.8.8; do ((cnt++)); echo "test '$cnt' - network down on $(date)"; sleep 60; done
```

Which will check once per-minute if the host `8.8.8.8` is available and report, for example:

```
test '10' - network down on Sat Dec 26 16:38:48 CST 2015
```

The script will terminate on its own once the network path is established.